# Java compile exception with kotlin(ReifiedParameterizedType cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class)

Tags: java, kotlin

I have error when try compile my java code with kotlin dependencies:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'functionBindingRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
class net.jodah.typetools.ReifiedParameterizedType cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class (net.jodah.typetools.ReifiedParameterizedType is in unnamed module of loader 'app';
java.lang.Class is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Why I get this exception? And how fix it?

upd:
If I add this dependency, then I have error.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I also see in debug that when spring try create `webSocketBuilder` (`java.util.function.Supplier<reactor.netty.http.client.WebsocketClientSpec$Builder>`) then I have this error. And error is ClassCastException because `java.util.function.Supplier<reactor.netty.http.client.WebsocketClientSpec$Builder>` can't be cast to `(Class<?>)`

But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: It would help if you showed us the code that caused the error, not just the error.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am not sure that I have code that throw it. I add dependency and then I get this error. But if I remove this dependency I don't have error.

Comment: What is that dependancy?

Comment: I have an error when spring try initialize `org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration`

Comment: Please see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2490 The issue is believed to be fixed. Also next time please tag it with spring-cloud-stream or spring-cloud-function